# Can you dynamically combine multiple conditional functions into one in Python?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm curious if it's possible to take several conditional functions and create one function that checks them all (e.g. the way a generator takes a procedure for iterating through a series and creates an iterator).

The basic usage case would be when you have a large number of conditional parameters (e.g. "max_a", "min_a", "max_b", "min_b", etc.), many of which could be blank.  They would all be passed to this "function creating" function, which would then return one function that checked them all.  Below is an example of a naive way of doing what I'm asking:

```
def combining_function(max_a, min_a, max_b, min_b, ...):
    f_array = []
    if max_a is not None:
        f_array.append( lambda x: x.a < max_a )
    if min_a is not None:
        f_array.append( lambda x: x.a > min_a )
    ...

    return lambda x: all( [ f(x) for f in f_array ] )
```

What I'm wondering is what is the most efficient to achieve what's being done above?  It seems like executing a function call for every function in f_array would create a decent amount of overhead, but perhaps I'm engaging in premature/unnecessary optimization.  Regardless, I'd be interested to see if anyone else has come across usage cases like this and how they proceeded.

Also, if this isn't possible in Python, is it possible in other (perhaps more functional) languages?

EDIT: It looks like the consensus solution is to compose a string containing the full collection of conditions and then use exec or eval to generate a single function.  @doublep suggests this is pretty hackish.  Any thoughts on how bad this is?  Is it plausible to check the arguments closely enough when composing the function that a solution like this could be considered safe?  After all, whatever rigorous checking is required only needs to be performed once whereas the benefit from a faster combined conditional can be accrued over a large number of calls.  Are people using stuff like this in deployment scenarios or is this mainly a technique to play around with?

Comment: Are all your conditional parameters going to be max/min pairs? It's definitely possible, but how to do it depends on what kind of tests you'll be doing.

Comment: Remove the list in the call to `all()`, i.e. just `all (f(x) for f in f_array)`.  This will stop early if any `f` produces a false value.

Comment: @doublep: this will work only with python recent enough. Some people still have to work with archaic versions ;-)

Comment: @liori: OK, you have a point.  Then ditching the lambda and returning a local function definition that does `for f in f_array: ...` will be more efficient.  The current version never stops early and creates a list object that's not required.

Comment: The spec is unclear. seems like first you want to check `min_a < x.a < max_a` but for the next pair check some other attribute, presumably `x.b`? And since args don't come with their names, no way to know what's the next argument to check!

Comment: @EnTerr: Yes, the next thing you would check (in this example) would be min_b < x.b < max_b.  In that case, how is the spec incomplete?  I'm not sure what you mean by "args don't come with their names, no way to know what's the next argument to check", can you clarify?

Comment: say i call `combining_function('foo','bar','baz','xyz','zzy','ezy')` - how would it know what's the first attribute name? the second attribute name? postulating they will be always ".a", ".b", ".c" and so on (til ".z" - and then what?) will be silly

Comment: @EnTerr: Well for this approach to make sense you have to use keyword arguments, I imagine in a deployment case you would force this with a function declaration like
    combining_function(**kwargs):

In the example above I was just trying to illustrate the internal logic so I didn't force the issue.

Comment: @erich (3 comments up): Your specification didn't say that the different checks should be for different attributes of the object... that's the kind of detail you need to provide. I would also ask whether you have the freedom to change the interface, because like J.F. Sebastian said, the way it's written is pretty silly.

Comment: @David: yes, the interface is pretty silly and totally changeable, it's only there for illustration purposes.  I'm really more interested in the details of whether Python provides a way to create functions dynamically similarly to how generators create iterators.  Thus far it seems like the leading suggestion is exec/eval, and that there is no "magic" way to do it in python without constructing the corresponding code strings dynamically.

Comment: @erich: If it's totally changeable, why not change it? I think the interface you came up with is getting in the way - it's putting the focus on what is essentially trying to make Python read its own source code, which is different from dynamically constructing functions. Python does have the ability to do a lot of things dynamically, but you're missing out on that because of the way you asked the question.

Comment: What would you suggest changing the interface to?  One parameter that is an array of conditions to check like this: {'operation': '<', 'member_name': 'a', 'comparison_value': 'max_a'} ?  Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing

```
return lambda x: all( [ f(x) for f in f_array ] )
```

with

```
return lambda x: all( f(x) for f in f_array )
```

will give a more efficient `lambda` as it will stop early if any `f` returns a false value and doesn't need to create unnecessary list.  This is only possible on Python 2.4 or 2.5 and up, though.  If you need to support ancient values, do the following:

```
def check (x):
    for f in f_array:
        if not f (x):
            return False
    return True

return check
```

Finally, if you *really* need to make this very efficient and are not afraid of bounding-on-hackish solutions, you could try compilation at runtime:

```
def combining_function (max_a, min_a):
    constants = { }
    checks    = []

    if max_a is not None:
        constants['max_a'] = max_a
        checks.append ('x.a < max_a')

    if min_a is not None:
        constants['min_a'] = min_a
        checks.append ('x.a > min_a')

    if not checks:
        return lambda x: True
    else:
        func = 'def check (x): return (%s)' % ') and ('.join (checks)
        exec func in constants, constants
        return constants['check']

class X:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

check = combining_function (3, 1)
print check (X (0)), check (X (2)), check (X (4))
```

Note that in Python 3.x `exec` becomes a function, so the above code is not portable.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, if your list of possible parameters is just a sequence of `max,min,max,min,max,min,...` then here's an easy way to do it:

```
def combining_function(*args):
    maxs, mins = zip(*zip(*[iter(args)]*2))
    minv = max(m for m in mins if m is not None)
    maxv = min(m for m in maxs if m is not None)
    return lambda x: minv < x.a < maxv
```

But this kind of "cheats" a bit: it precomputes the smallest maximum value and the largest minimum value. If your tests can be something more complicated than just max/min testing, the code will need to be modified.

Comment: Oops, I missed the `.a` in the question... I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: well here lies a problem, the spec is unclear. seems like you need to check `min_a < x.a < max_a` but for the next pair check some other attribute, presumably 'x.b'. And since args don't come with their names, no way to know what's the next argument to check!

Comment: @EnTerr: Of course if I'd interpreted the question that way I would have written something else. You're right that it's unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The `combining_function()` interface is horrible, but if you can't change it then you could use:

```
def combining_function(min_a, max_a, min_b, max_b):
    conditions = []
    for name, value in locals().items():
        if value is None:
            continue
        kind, sep, attr = name.partition("_")
        op = {"min": ">", "max": "<"}.get(kind, None)
        if op is None:
            continue
        conditions.append("x.%(attr)s %(op)s %(value)r" % dict(
            attr=attr, op=op, value=value))

    if conditions:
        return eval("lambda x: " + " and ".join(conditions), {})
    else:
        return lambda x: True
```

Comment: `combining_function(None, None, None, type('', (), {'__repr__': lambda x:'os.system("sudo rm -rf /")'})())` ;-)

Comment: The interface was just demonstration purposes, what would you suggest as an ideal interface for this kind of problem?

Comment: @liori: I don't see your point. You could just as easily write `type('',(),{'__lt__': lambda x,y: os.system("whatever")})()`.

Comment: @erich: If there are many min/max pairs then an incremental improvement to the interface might be `get_inrange(a=(None,1), b=(1, 2))` -> `get_inrange = lambda **kwargs: lambda x: all(op(getattr(x, attr), value) for attr, minmax in kwargs.items() for op, value in zip([operator.gt, operator.lt], minmax) if value is not None)`

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: my point is that this code needs to check its arguments or clearly state that it is unsafe for some inputs; otherwise "eval" could do anything.

Comment: @liori: My point is that *most* of Python code is unsafe if it is not stated otherwise as the example from my comment demonstrates. http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2008/03/03/restricted_python.html